# How canI generate jwt -php token send and reviced token and check validate

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, jwt

I'm trying to generate PHP Token using this library , 
https://github.com/lcobucci/jwt/blob/3.2/README.md
, I executed this code :

```
$signer = new Sha256();

$token = (new Builder())->setIssuer('http://example.com') // Configures the issuer (iss claim)
                        ->setAudience('http://example.org') // Configures the audience (aud claim)
                        ->setId('4f1g23a12aa', true) // Configures the id (jti claim), replicating as a header item
                        ->setIssuedAt(time()) // Configures the time that the token was issue (iat claim)
                        ->setNotBefore(time() + 60) // Configures the time that the token can be used (nbf claim)
                        ->setExpiration(time() + 3600) // Configures the expiration time of the token (exp claim)
                        ->set('uid', 1) // Configures a new claim, called "uid"
                        ->sign($signer, 'testing') // creates a signature using "testing" as key
                        ->getToken(); // Retrieves the generated token
```

How can I check if request coming with this sign : -`>sign($signer, 'testing')`

```
var_dump($token->verify($signer, 'testing 1')); // false, because the key is different
var_dump($token->verify($signer, 'testing')); // true, because the key is the same
```

this function to check if sign is correct but , i need to check token with sign coming from request .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved that using this library :

https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt

generate new token :

```
$key = "example_key";
$token = array(
    "iss" => "http://example.org",
    "aud" => "http://example.com",
    "iat" => 1356999524,
    "nbf" => 1357000000
);

/**
 * IMPORTANT:
 * You must specify supported algorithms for your application. See
 * https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-jose-json-web-algorithms-40
 * for a list of spec-compliant algorithms.
 */
$jwt = JWT::encode($token, $key); 
$decoded = JWT::decode($jwt, $key, array('HS256'));

print_r($decoded);
```

$jwt = JWT::encode($token, $key);// this one to generate new token with your key ($key = "example_key";)

to output token use this line :

```
echo $jwt ;
```

to check if this token sign in your key use this .

```
$decoded = JWT::decode($coming_token , $key, array('HS256'));
```